# SOLR add support for phrase fuzzy match case insensitive

Tags: solr, fuzzy-search

I am new to SOLR, I have set up a core, I am working on adding schema, I need to ad a field on which I should be able to do fuzzy phrase match.

for example I need to search "dummy Printer Gallery five" in following text.

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
>   since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
>   scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
>   five centuries.

i.e. will be case insensitive

any suggestions please.

Best regards
Faisal

Answer (score 2):

You've got a couple of problems here. I'll give hints, but you may want to research them separately.

1. Case-insensitive search is done in Solr by having analyzer chain include a LowerCaseFilterFactory. That's in most of the examples that ship with Solr, so just use a correct type as a start
2. If you need "printing" to match "printer", you need stemming. Solr has a collection of different ones, again all over the example configurations. [text_en](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/releases/lucene-solr/6.0.0/solr/example/example-DIH/solr/db/conf/managed-schema#L463) shows both lowercasing and stemming.
3. Matching long phrases with things in between is a bit trickier, but a good start would be to try using eDisMax and apply generous [slope](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheExtendedDisMaxQueryParser-Using%27slop%27). Deal with this problem in isolation to anything else, if it does not work straight away.

Comment: if he sets is default query operator to OR it will match any individual word from his phrase with closer matches ranked higher. Also printer is in the text to be matched but Gallery isn't but stemming might work for this. BTW I gave you a +1 Alexandra for your answer.